# Are folder permissions on a web server adequate security?

Tags: security, permissions

I'm working on a project which uses a folder full of flat-file databases. I'd like to make sure these databases are only accessible to scripts running off the server, so I set the folder permissions to 700.

This results in all scripts functioning properly, but a 403 Forbidden whenever I try to access the database folder in my browser. This is good.

However, I'm wondering: am I missing something? Is there any way — short of gaining access to my FTP account – for an outside user to access this folder? Or can I rest easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper solution is storing them outside the document root. If you cannot do that, but know that Apache will be used, create a `.htaccess` in the folder with the following contents:

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
```

Using filesystem permissions may or may not work depending on the environment - in a perfect setup the webserver would use the same uid as your system user that owns the files. Then your approach wouldn't work.